# Difference between Task (System.Threading.Task) and Thread

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

From what I understand about the difference between Task & Thread is that task happened in the thread-pool while the thread is something that I need to managed by myself .. ( and that task can be cancel and return to the thread-pool in the end of his mission )

But in some blog I read that if the operating system need to create task and create thread => it will be easier to create ( and destroy ) task.

Someone can explain please why creating task is simple that thread ?

( or maybe I missing something here ... )

Comment: What's the difference between a *job* and a *worker*?  A worker *does* a job; a worker is not *a job*. Some jobs are done by a single worker; some jobs are broken up into smaller jobs all performed by many workers working together. Same with tasks and threads; a task is not *a kind of thread*; a task is a job, and a thread is a worker that does the job.

Comment: Another analogy I've heard is that processors are drivers, threads are trucks, and tasks are loads to be hauled around.  A driver (processor) can only operate one truck (thread) at a time, and a truck (thread) can only haul one load (task) at a time.  You can buy as many trucks as you want, but the more time that drivers take switching between trucks the less time they spend driving.  Loads can be piled up in a warehouse waiting for transportation, and the warehouse can prioritize them and assign them to trucks based on whatever rules make sense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I *think* that what you are talking about when you say Task is a [System.Threading.Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx).  If that's the case then you can think about it this way:

- A program can have many threads, but a processor core can only run one Thread at a time.

  - Threads are ***very*** expensive, and switching between the threads that are running is also very expensive.
  - So... Having thousands of threads doing stuff is inefficient.  Imagine if your teacher gave *you* 10,000 tasks to do.  You'd spend so much time cycling between them that you'd never get anything done.  The same thing can happen to the CPU if you start too many threads.

To get around this, the .NET framework allows you to create Tasks.  Tasks are a bit of work bundled up into an object, and they allow you to do interesting things like capture the output of that work and chain pieces of work together (*first* go to the store, *then* buy a magazine).

Tasks are scheduled on a pool of threads.  The specific number of threads depends on the scheduler used, but the default scheduler tries to pick a number of threads that is optimal for the number of CPU cores that you have and how much time your tasks are spending actually using CPU time.  If you want to, you can even write your own scheduler that does something specific like making sure that all Tasks for that scheduler always operate on a single thread.

So think of Tasks as items in your to-do list.  You might be able to do 5 things at once, but if your boss gives you 10000, they will pile up in your inbox until the first 5 that you are doing get done.  The difference between Tasks and the ThreadPool is that Tasks (as I mentioned earlier) give you better control over the relationship between different items of work (imagine to-do items with multiple instructions stapled together), whereas the ThreadPool just allows you to queue up a bunch of individual, single-stage items (Functions).

Comment: `Task`s are scheduled on the `ThreadPool` by default, but they don't have to be. There may not even be any code associated directly with a `Task`, if you create it using a `TaskCompletionSource`.

Answer (score 13):

You are hearing two different notions of task.  The first is the notion of a job, and the second is the notion of a process.

A long time ago (in computer terms), there were no threads.  Each running instance of a program was called a process, since it simply performed one step after another after another until it exited.  This matches the intuitive idea of a process as a series of steps, like that of a factory assembly line.  The operating system manages the process abstraction.

Then, developers began to add multiple assembly lines to the factories.  Now a program could do more than one thing at once, and either a library or (more commonly today) the operating system would manage the scheduling of the steps within each thread.  A thread is kind of a lightweight process, but a thread belongs to a process, and all the threads in a process share memory.  On the other hand, multiple processes can't mess with each others' memory.  So, the multiple threads in your web server can each access the same information about the connection, but Word can't access Excel's in-memory data structures because Word and Excel are running as separate processes.  The idea of a process as a series of steps doesn't really match the model of a process with threads, so some people took to calling the "abstraction formerly known as a process" a task.  This is the second definition of task that you saw in the blog post.  Note that plenty of people still use the word process to mean this thing.

Well, as threads became more commmon, developers added even more abstractions over top of them to make them easier to use.  This led to the rise of the thread pool, which is a library-managed "pool" of threads.  You pass the library a job, and the library picks a thread and runs the job on that thread.  The .NET framework has a thread pool implementation, and the first time you heard about a "task" the documentation really meant a job that you pass to the thread pool.

So in a sense, both the documentation and the blog post are right.  The overloading of the term task is the unfortunate source of confusion.

Comment: +1 this is a nice explanation.  I think that the OP is talking about `System.Threading.Task` though.  It would be nice if you can extend the discussion slightly more to include the nuances of TPL.

Answer (score 8):

Threads have been a part of .Net from v1.0,  Tasks were introduced in the Task Parallel Library TPL which was released in .Net 4.0.

You can consider a Task as a more sophisticated version of a Thread. They are very easy to use and have a lot of advantages over Threads as follows:

1. You can create return types to Tasks as if they are functions.
2. You can the "ContinueWith" method, which will wait for the previous task and then start the execution. (Abstracting wait)
3. Abstracts Locks which should be avoided as per guidlines of my company.
4. You can use Task.WaitAll and pass an array of tasks so you can wait till all tasks are complete.
5. You can attach task to the parent task, thus you can decide whether the parent or the child will exist first.
6. You can achieve data parallelism with LINQ queries.
7. You can create parallel for and foreach loops
8. Very easy to handle exceptions with tasks.
9. *Most important thing is if the same code is run on single core machine it will just act as a single process without any overhead of threads.

Disadvantage of tasks over threads:

1. You need .Net 4.0
2. Newcomers who have learned operating systems can understand threads better.
3. New to the framework so not much assistance available.

Some tips:-
Always use Task.Factory.StartNew method which is semantically perfect and standard.

Take a look at Task Parallel Libray for more information
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the comment by Eric Lippert:

`Thread`s are a way that allows your application to do several things in parallel. For example, your application might have one thread that processes the events from the user, like button clicks, and another thread that performs some long computation. This way, you can do two different things “at the same time”. If you didn't do that, the user wouldn't be to click buttons until the computation finished. So, `Thread` is something that can execute some code you wrote.

`Task`, on the other hand represents an abstract notion of some job. That job can have a result, and you can wait until the job finishes (by calling `Wait()`) or say that you want to do something after the job finishes (by calling `ContinueWith()`).

The most common job that you want to represent is to perform some computation in parallel with the current code. And `Task` offers you a simple way to do that. How and when the code actually runs is defined by `TaskScheduler`. The default one uses a `ThreadPool`: a set of threads that can run any code. This is done because creating and switching threads in inefficient.

But `Task` doesn't have to be directly associated with some code. You can use [`TaskCompletionSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174.aspx) to create a `Task` and then set its result whenever you want. For example, you could create a `Task` and mark it as completed when the user clicks a button. Some other code could wait on that `Task` and while it's waiting, there is no code executing for that `Task`.

If you want to know when to use `Task` and when to use `Thread`: `Task` is simpler to use and more efficient that creating your own `Thread`s. But sometimes, you need more control than what is offered by `Task`. In those cases, it makese sense to use `Thread` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks really are just a wrapper for the boilerplate code of spinning up threads manually. At the root, there is no difference. Tasks just make the management of threads easier, as well as they are generally more expressive due to the lessening of the boilerplate noise.

Comment: Chris, Can you pls explain about the Task scheduled ?

Comment: I'll add an answer, but I would also direct you to @AdamMihalcin's answer

Comment: @ChrisShain I agree that Tasks are scheduled on threads, and was not trying to imply that threads are the same as Tasks, but that the same development goals are accomplished. Maybe my explanation is a little too generalized...

Comment: @JustinPihony yeah, it just led the uninformed reader to the wrong conclusion.  I think the edit is more accurate.  +1