# how to receive data from several sockets in terms of multithreading?

Tags: c#

I want to rephrase my previous question [Should I replace all my "new Thread" with "Task.Factory.StartNew"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727521/should-i-replace-all-my-new-thread-with-task-factory-startnew)

I need to listen for several udp sockets

```
................
s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
........

public void Receive()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            count = s.Receive(buffer);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return;
        }
        if (count > 0)
        {
            OnNewDatagram(new NewDatagramEventArgs(buffer, count));
        }
    }
}
```

So I need to launch several "Receive()" methods (one for each socket).
Now I'm using one Thread for one socket:

```
socketA = new...
....
threadA = new Thread(Receive);
.....
threadA.Start();

socketB = new...
....
threadB = new Thread(Receive);
.....
threadB.Start();
```

What should I use:

- one thread for one socket
- one thread for all sockets(how?)
- one task for all sockets
- one task for one socket
- other?

**upd** I have only 2-3 sockets, so it's probably better to use one-socket-one-thread model instead of Socket.Select... or one-socket-one-task model?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Socket.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300760.aspx#S5) to wait on several sockets and handle incoming data on any of them.

Comment: why it's better than using one-thread-per-socket model? from article it is not clear that `Socket.Select` is better...

Comment: Well, because you don't have on thread per socket. Threads are costly, and in your case most of the time they'll just wait for sockets. You'll get the same I/O performance without the additional threads.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you should use a new thread for each socket, because if you use the same thread for all the sockets, you would only get one stream, the one that got first.