# when to use Task and when to use Thread?

Tags: c#

I've just asked question about Task but realized that I actually want to ask more general question.
Could someone summarize pros and cons of Tasks and Threads.
How to understand should I use Task or Thread?

Comment: I've answered a similar (but not quite the same) question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9493446/960195).  Hope it comes in handy.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin I'm looking for algorithm which can answer what should I use in each particular case - Task or Thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493421/different-between-task-system-threading-task-and-thread#comment12019624_9493421

Comment: The first thing to understand is *what the difference is between a task and a thread*. "Make me a sandwich" is a task. Hiring a chef is creating a thread. If you confuse those two things then you are going to either hire a whole lot of unnecessary chefs that you then cannot eat, or you are going to be asking a pile of sandwiches to make you dinner. The way you decide whether to use a task or a thread is to decide whether you want to represent *the task* in code *irrespective of who performs the task*, or whether you want to represent *the worker* that performs the task.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4130194/884410) may help

Comment: @EricLippert it seems msdn suggest to use Task even as "workers": "in the .NET Framework 4, tasks are the preferred API for writing multi-threaded, asynchronous, and parallel code."

Comment: @javapowered: They are the preferred way to go, because they refocus your code to emphasize *the tasks being performed* and not *the workers that are performing them*. Most problems with threading code arise from the difficulties of coordinating the workers -- the threads. If you are in the business of eating sandwiches, it is better to be able to say "I need a hundred sandwiches" and let the task library work out how many cooks to hire.

Comment: @javapowered: The reason Tasks are recommended is because rarely are people concerned with the chef (to follow Eric's example), they just want a sandwich. So recommending Task as default gets the majority of people what they want. However if you need a chef, you need a chef, and will by no means be hurt by using Threads in that case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130194/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-thread

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Task` is an order to  program to do something in asynchronous way. The `Thread` is actually `OS` kernel object which *executes* what was requested. Think about `Task` like a clever thread aggregator/organizer that "knows" how much task is better to run contemporary on your `CPU`. It's just cleverer then common implementations of multi-threading (that's why it's suggested choice from Microsoft). It's a feature that helps you managing `Threads` in easier way.

Look also on this [Should i use ThreadPools or Task Parallel Library for IO-bound operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213695/should-i-use-threadpools-or-task-parallel-library-for-io-bound-operations) that may give you some hints on performance issues you may be interested in.